# "unbound method connect()" error while connecting to Testlink through python

Tags: python, testlink

```
from XMLRPC.TestLinkAPI.src import testlink
class ConnectToTestLink:

    TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL = "abc.com";
    TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY = "e9e245fdhsgfdsghfd18e9"
    tls = testlink.TestLinkHelper.connect(testlink.TestlinkAPIClient)
    #tls.countProjects();
```

I am getting the error below:

```
unbound method connect() must be called with TestLinkHelper instance as first argument (got type instance instead)
```

(For reference, I am following this url: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TestLink-API-Python-client )

Comment: You are calling connect() on the class instead of on an instance of the class. Compare your 6th line with the doc: `tls = testlink.TestLinkHelper().connect(testlink.TestlinkAPIClient)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 tls = testlink.TestLinkHelper(ConnectToTestLink.TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL,
                                  ConnectToTestLink.TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY).connect(testlink.TestlinkAPIClient)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just for yourself! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44411937/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
from testlink import TestlinkAPIGeneric, TestLinkHelper
```

and then

```
TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL = "abc.com";
TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY = "e9e245fdhsgfdsghfd18e9"

my_test_link = TestLinkHelper(TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL, TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY).connect(TestlinkAPIGeneric)
```